# Re-render only specific element which is generated by a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a listing page which looks like a calendar listing for a month.

I want to re-render only specific division when some action happens on some date and I receive new date for that particular date.

That means , only specific `<div className="badgeInfo">`

My render method looks like this:

```
<div>
{
Object.keys(this.state.monthData).map((eachDayInfo) => {

    return (
        <div className="eachDate">
            
            <div className="dayInfo">
            <div>{this.state.monthData[eachDayInfo].weekdayName}</div>
            <div>{this.state.monthData[eachDayInfo].date}</div>
            </div>

            {
            Array.isArray(this.state.badgesInfo) && (this.state.badgesInfo).length > 0
            ?
            (
                this.getDataPerDate(this.state.badgesInfo).length > 0
                ?
                (
                <div className="badgeInfo">
                {
                    Object.entries(this.state.badgesInfo).map( eachItem => {
                    return this.generateBadge(eachItem);
                    })
                }
                </div>
                )
                :
                null
            )
            :
            null
            }
        </div>
    );

});
}

</div>
```

Can any one suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: `I want to re-render only specific division...` Why? Are you experiencing a problem? What is the problem?

Comment: To avoid re-rendering all the 30 days...
I want to update the information in one particular day after rendering it once..

Comment: Please, I cannot stress enough that you shouldn't worry about what react is doing unless you experience performance or other issues. At this point, react exposes several perf-optimization tools, but don't use them until and unless you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Not that the below pattern changes your logic or prevents re-renders, but I try to avoid complex logic like this, purely because it's hard to read. Breaking down the complex logic into components preserves the the functionality, and makes reading (and understanding it) trivial. Below is a partial example of what I mean:

```
// the job of this component is to just render DayInfo components in a loop
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(this.state.monthData).map((eachDayInfo) => (
        <DayInfo 
         key={eachDayInfo.date} 
         {...eachDayInfo}
         badge={...something here}
        />
      ))}
   </div>
  )
}
```

```
// the job of this component is to hold the logic for rendering a day
const DayInfo = props => (
 <div className="eachDate">
  <div className="dayInfo">
   <div>{props.weekdayName}</div>
   <div>{props.date}</div>
   {
     props.badge ? <DayBadge {...props.badge}/> : null
   }
  </div>
 </div>
)
```

```
// the job of this component is to render the badge for a day
const DayBadge = props => (
  <div className='badgeInfo'> ... </div>
)
```

To be 100% clear, you do not need to worry about preventing re-renders unless you are experiencing a performance issue. If you are experiencing a bug that is solved by preventing re-renders, you need to fix the actual bug, not prevent the re-renders.

Comment: Your solution to complexity is nice and I like it very much. But the question is about re-rendering the badges of a particular day, based on the updated data from server for that day without re-rendering all other day badges.

Comment: See my comment on the original question, ignore everything that react does until and unless you experience performance or other issues. React is blazing fast out of the box and most people don't ever need to use the perf optimization tools that it exposes. Re-rendering 30 days for react is inconsequential.

Comment: It is not about performance issue. 
My project management wants to apply reload/re-rendering for the cell which has a data modification. The badges in a specific day need to render again after the new set of information is received.

Comment: @dxb_dev - they will. If they aren't it's because you've mutated props or state and has nothing to do with this question at all. Show me the code where you are updating the badge data.